# Fallout Shelter Exploring the Wastland

Tags: fallout-shelter

My Shelter has been going pretty well so I decided to send one of my deweller to the Wasteland. I prepered him by giving lots of Stimpacks, Guns and ect... But he dosen't seem to be using any of the things to pretect himslef... How do I help him?

Answer (score 4):

Your dweller will automatically use the Stimpacks when he becomes injured enough. Ditto for Radaway with radiation. You can see his health and how irradiated he is by clicking on the Wasteland. It will bring up a list of all your dwellers who are out there that you can scroll through. You can also see the gun that he's wielding. A bigger gun will minimise the damage he gets in each encounter, but even if he wins, he's still likely to get damage, and can even die after a successful encounter if his health is low enough and he's out of Stimpacks.

The only thing you can do to help your dweller is to recall him. It will take half as long for him to get back to the Vault and he will suffer no further damage or increased radiation on his way back. If he was wandering for 26 hours it will take him 13 hours to get back. If he dies in the Wasteland he can be revived for a certain number of caps, just like the dwellers in the Vault after an attack.

Comment: @MissyEloise If you're playing on survival mode, or ever do, note that dwellers that die while exploring cannot be revived, and all their stuff is lost, unless they have a pet with them, which will bring back the stuff.